# What is wrong in the following program?

Tags: c

I am using the fgets() and sscanf() combination to read two chars. But something doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here?

```
    puts("Enter two floats: ");
    fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
    sscanf(buf,"%lf%lf",&fx,&fy);
    printf("Values are %lf and %lf\n", fx, fy);

    puts("Enter two characters: ");
    fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%c%c",&cx, &cy);
    printf("Values are %c and %c\n", cx, cy);
```

That code gives the following output:

```
Enter two floats:
4.5 5.5
Values are 4.5 and 5.5
Enter two characters:
s f
Values are s and
```

Why?

Comment: `scanf(buf, "%c%c",&cx, &cy);` --> `sscanf(buf, "%c %c",&cx, &cy);`, Also `scanf(buf,"%f%f",&fx,&fy);` ditto. and use "%lf" for double `sscanf(buf,"%lf%lf",&fx,&fy);`

Comment: `scanf`s are supposed to be `sscanf`s

Comment: Always check return value of any *scanf* function. Also better check return values of IO functions like *fgets*, so you do not end up trying to parse a buffer which wasn't actually read to.

Comment: now, `"%c%c"` --> `"%c %c"` or you enter `sf`.

Comment: @Shravan _Why is everybody downvoting?_ : "answers to every question about programming." Quote from the preface of the this site. this site isn't debugging services. So questions like this will be hated.(do it yourself!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add spaces before each `%c` in the `sscanf`. This is done to discard all blanks from the `stdin`. As these blanks like `\n`,spaces will be present in the `stdin` , it will be taken by the next call to `fgets` and also one `%c` because it is also a character. Also use `%lf` for `double` and not `%f`.`%f` is for `float`.